# Editable CSS by editing text on textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a `textarea` which has the stylesheet of the web page inside it?

I want to make a web page which a user can customize its `<style>` settings by editing text inside a `textarea`.

Here's what I have done so far; inside the `<textarea>` of this code snippet is the editable text which I intend to make it function as the web page's stylesheet, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

I did many web search looking for solutions, but could not find useful help regarding this particular function. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML = "document.getElementById('input').value;";
}
```

```html
<p>sample text</p>
<textarea id="input" oninput="myFunction()" rows="5">p {
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 15px;
}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, but your code has 2 problems.

1. `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array, so you need to select the first element of the array using `[0]`.
2. You are not actually getting the input element, you're just using a string of the code you want to run (i.e. you want to run the code `document.getElementById('input').value` but you've put quotes around it, which turns it into a string).

This updated version should work:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
}
```

```html
<p>sample text</p>
<textarea id="input" oninput="myFunction()" rows="5">html {
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 15px;
}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use inline styles with the display style set to "block" and the contenteditable attribute set to "true".

**Example:**

```
<div>
  <style style="
      display: block; 
      padding: 0 0.5rem; 
      border: 1px solid black; 
      border-radius: 4px;
      white-space: pre;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
      font-size: small;
      " 
      contenteditable="true">
    #myDiv {
      height: 100%;
      --l1: repeating-linear-gradient(-60deg, 
        transparent 0, 
        transparent 5px, 
        rgba(210, 180, 140, 0.5) 0, 
        rgba(210, 180, 140, 0.5) 35px);
      --l0: repeating-linear-gradient(60deg,
        transparent 0, 
        transparent 5px,
        rgba(210, 180, 140, 0.5) 0, 
        rgba(210, 180, 140, 0.5) 35px);
      background: var(--l1), var(--l0);
      }
  </style>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

This will directly allow to edit and alter the contents of the style definitions by the user, without the direct possibility to save the modifications.